# While printing the length of list showing wrong output while debuging it showing crct output

Tags: python-3.x

While printing the length of list showing wrong output while debuging it showing crct output
I had a list of 6 items but while printing it showing 1 while debuging it showing 6
Can anyone help me

Comment: What list are you talking about and what is the output ? Can you post your program ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dev shows your code, it's not clear if you want to len in the list or if you want to go for it.
If you are trying to count with len() it would be like this:

`var = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

`print(len(var))`

`> result: 6`

if you are printing each item like this:

`print(var[1])`

`print(var[2])`

remember that a vector starts at 0,
in your case it would be from 0 to 5

Comment: def verify_patient_list()
intRowNumber = 10
    intColNumber = 1
    StudyBrowserPanelModule.studyBrowserPanelModule.doClickOnCellByIndex(intRowNumber, intColNumber)
    # Check if data exists for visit
    visitCnt = StudyBrowserPanelModule.studyBrowserPanelModule.doGetVisitRowCount()
    print(type(visitCnt))
    print(visitCnt, "This is from line 68")
    print(StudyBrowserPanelModule.studyBrowserPanelModule.doGetVisitRowCount())
    logUtil.logger.info("{0} row of data exists in the table".format(visitCnt))